# Ordering of entities in an ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I have a system that models some domain data in an ontology, the usual sort of triplestore.

I've been looking around for a way to express plurality and ordering but haven't found anything via the googles. My main use case is something like one entity in the domain can be a list of tasks, (get groceries, cook meal, eat meal, something like that) but in general I feel like having the ability to 'weight' your edges might be useful across the board.

Is there an accepted way of doing this? Just go to a quadstore? Intermediary items (list → listitem) with edges to an ordinality and a domain entity? Predicates from predicates to Weights?

Here's an example:

[image: Example layout]

Comment: An example might elicit more response.  In particular, I'm not sure what you mean by plurality; I'm guessing that you understand the owl cardinality features and they won't do what you need - but I can't guess what you need.

Comment: @EdStaub, yeah cardinality is good but I'm sort of looking for ordinality. An example is a list of tasks: `1. put on socks, 2. put on shoes, 3. leave the house`. I want to be able to encode order in my predicates. (In this situation, I'd have an entity in my schema called DoList which would have a Predicate from DoList to Tasks, with no max cardinality)

Comment: Do you just want an encoding of a sequence? You can code up a list pretty easily, or you can make an tertiary relation, e.g., "hasTask(thing,rank,task)" such that "hasTask(taskList,1,socks), hasTask(taskList,2,shoes), etc."

Comment: Possibly relevant for creating lists: [Difference Between OWL-LIST and RDF-LIST](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11681662/1281433), [Modelling OWL datatype property restrictions with a list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18785499/1281433).

Comment: Possibly relevant for n-ary relations: [Representing complicated sentences using RDF syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16476051/1281433), [OWL Ontology Predicate Logic with Jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18560657/1281433), [Inferencing in protege](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16972311/1281433).

Comment: Thanks for the links, Josh - I'll read through em. The idea is to avoid making tertiary+ relations if at all possible.

Comment: You may prefer a list based solution then.  It's easy enough to work with in SPARQL, but it'll be more awkward to with DL queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To represent something like what you've shown in your figure, you'd typically treat it as an n-ary relation.  You should have a look at the W3C working note [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/), but the short version is that you've got a 3-ary relation, and you're expressing

```
hasTask(list,1,socks)
hasTask(list,2,shoes)
hasTask(list,3,leash)
```

For each one of those, you'd have a resource, usually a blank node, but it could be a URI, too, and have properties relating it to the various components, and perhaps a type:

```
_:rel1 rdf:type :taskItem ;
       :hasList :list ;
       :hasord  1;
       :hasTask :socks .
_:rel2 rdf:type :taskItem ;
       :hasList :list ;
       :hasord  2;
       :hasTask :shoes .
_:rel3 rdf:type :taskItem ;
       :hasList :list ;
       :hasord  3;
       :hasTask :leash .
```

There's some variability here, of course.  Rather than having the reified relation have the list, number, and task as property values, the list could be related to each task item:

```
:list :hasTaskItem [ rdf:type :taskItem ;
                     :hasord  1;
                     :hasTask :socks ] ,
                   [ rdf:type :taskItem ;
                     :hasord  2;
                     :hasTask :shoes ] ,
                   [ rdf:type :taskItem ;
                     :hasord  3;
                     :hasTask :leash ] .
```

The basic idea is the same though.  Alternatively, you could use a list.  In pure RDF, you can use RDF lists and leave the numbers implicit, like:

```
:list :hasTasks ( :socks :shoes :leash ) .
```

That's just shorthand for

```
:list :hasTasks [ rdf:first :socks ;
                  rdf:rest [ rdf:first :shoes ;
                             rdf:rest [ rdf:first :leash ;
                                        rdf:rest rdf:nil ]]].
```

In OWL, you can't use rdf:first and rdf:rest, but you can define your own analogous properties and implement the same structures.  There's an example of specifying a list class in my answer ot [Can I specify a range for rdf:List members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474738/1281433) (where someone wanted a list all of whose elements had to be a certain type).  If you do take this route, and you want to recover the position of each element in the list, you can actually do it using a SPARQL query over the RDF, as I've described in an answer to [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17523804/1281433).

Comment: Thanks again for the leads. I'm about to go home for the evening but will follow up (with questions?) and make sure you get your accept tomorrow. Cheers

Comment: @ap could you please tell, are there any news about this case?