# How to model temporal data property using Protégé

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, temporal

I have some data about water quality in several counties, it’s a set of month average indicators. This data is in the form

```
countyName | indicatorName | indicatorValue | indicatorMonth | indicatorYear
```

How can I model an ontology to represent this data using OWL and Protégé? I first tried to create a class for the counties and data properties for every indicator, but I really don't see how to model this temporal dimension associated to the indicators values.

Comment: Have a look at [Ordering of entities in an ontology](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398297/1281433).  In general, it sounds like you're asking about n-ary relations, in which case, look at [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you have tabular data with columns like countyName, indicatorName, indicatorValue, indicatorMonth, indicatorYear, then the typical way to encode this is as an n-ary relation.  See  [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) for more details, but the general idea is that you'd do something like this:

```
_:record72 rdf:type :WaterQualityRecord ;
           countryName "some country" ;
           indicatorName "some indicator" ;
           indicatorValue 42 ;
           indicatorMonth 9 ;     # e.g., for September
           indicatorYear 2013 .   # e.g., for 2013

_:record73 rdf:type :WaterQualityRecord ;
           countryName "some other country" ;
           indicatorName "some other indicator" ;
           indicatorValue 89 ;
           indicatorMonth 3 ;     # e.g., for March
           indicatorYear 2014 .   # e.g., for 2014
```

Then ordering by date is a simple matter of ordering first by indicatorYear and then by indicatorMonth.  You might also consider combining those properties into a single property whose value is an xsd:dateTime, but that's not quite as important.